# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 80, 60, 3) for Tensor 'input/X:0', which has shape '(?, 80, 60, 1)'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was trying to recreate a program that Sentdex been doing in "python plays gta V" series but when i come to train the ai it turn me this error: `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 80, 60, 3) for Tensor 'input/X:0', which has shape '(?, 80, 60, 1)'` i was trying to canche sme parameters but it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from alexnet import alexnet
import time
width=80
height=60
lr=1e-3
epochs=30
model_name='minecraft-ai-{}-{}-{}'.format(lr,'ghostbot',epochs)
model=alexnet(width,height,lr)
train_data=np.load('training_data.npy',allow_pickle=True)
train=train_data[:-500]
test=train_data[-500:]
X=np.array([i[0]for i in train]).reshape(-1,width,height,3)
Y=[i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,width,height,3)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]
print(X.shape)
print(test_x.shape)
time.sleep(3)


model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=epochs, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
    snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=model_name,)
model.save(model_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the source at this path - https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/master/2.%20train_model.py#L91. It seems the line #91 has been changed to:

```
test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,width,height,3)
```

so you need to edit the last axis (number of channels) to `3` so that the last dimension (channels) of the test images matches that of the train ones. Make the same changes to debug this. Hope this helps!

Comment: well it still doeasn't work and shows the same error

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the new error you're getting?

Comment: The errror is the same as prevous

Comment: do you know the solution? @Balraj Ashwath

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because, number of channels in training images does not match input layer architecture.

If you are using grayscale images, in alexnet model definition and change

Line 728 from

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, width, height, 3], name='input')
```

to this

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, width, height, 1], name='input')
```

https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/master/models.py#L728